# How to get different type summation from datagridview in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#-2.0

I have windows form application datagridview which has two columns Salary and Currency

| Salary | Currency |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | USD |
| 200 | EURO |
| 300 | USD |
| 400 | EURO |

**Now I want to sum just USD from the above datagridview into total Textbox**

My code is:

```
double total=0;
             
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgSalary.Rows)
            {
                total += double.Parse(rw.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                lblTotal.Text = total.ToString();
            }
```